# How can I check if my Entity object is lazy loading?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I have two entity classes that have a one-to-many relationship.

```
public class Call : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class User : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Call> Calls { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a view model for 'Call' operations on the web layer.

```
public class CallVm : IViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserFullname { get; set; }
}
```

And I use a method to convert my 'Call' object to 'CallVm' object.
This method is briefly as follows.

```
public CallVm MapCallVm(Call call)
{
    return call == null ? null : new CallVm { Id = call.Id, UserFullname = call.User?.Fullname };
}
```

When I read the 'Call' entity from the database, I sometimes include 'User' and sometimes I don't. When I do not include it, there is no User property definition in the Call object because it is lazy loading. Therefore, I get the following error in MapCallVm method.

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

Is there a way to check this? I just want to assign `UserFullname = call.User?.Fullname` when there is a eager load. 
The only solution I can think of is controlling with try-catch. Is there a different solution?

Comment: you could disable lazy loading then you would know as it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DbReferenceEntry.IsLoaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbreferenceentry-2.isloaded?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) Property.

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the entity has been loaded
>   from the database.

```
if (_dbContext.Entry(Call).Reference(e => e.User).IsLoaded)
```

**Updated**

If you are getting value without `dbContext`, you should force the query to `Eager loading` instead.

Read the following post to have a better understanding.

[Should we disable lazy loading of Entity Framework in web apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54386019/should-we-disable-lazy-loading-of-entity-framework-in-web-apps)

Comment: I do not have access to the dbContext object in 'MapCallVm' method. I need to do this control without mixing the context class. Can't I control it directly over the 'Call' object? For this I wrote a code like this:

Comment: `public CallVm MapCallVm(Call call)
            {
                string userFullName;
                try { userFullName = call.User?.Username; }
                catch { userFullName = null; }
                return call == null ? null : new CallVm { Id = HashidsHelper.Encrypt(call.Id), ContactId = HashidsHelper.Encrypt(call.ContactId), UserFullname = userFullName, IsAccess = call.IsAccess, Date = call.Date };
            } `

Comment: If you are getting value without `dbContext`, you should force the query to `Eager loading` instead. Anyway, your code is okie. But It's not a good way.

Comment: You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54386019/should-we-disable-lazy-loading-of-entity-framework-in-web-apps) link to have a better understanding.

Comment: Phong is right - try to avoid passing database entities to your views

Answer (score 0):

As [@Phong's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60069776/9071943) - avoid passing DbContext. Normally, your repository class should map DB entities to simple POCO/DTO objects.

I suggest to introduce mapper class. This will help you to unit test your logic

```
// Interface to inject to repository
public interface ICallMapper
{
    CallVm Map(Call call);
}

public class CallMapper : ICallMapper
{
    public CallVm Map(Call call)
    {
        return call == null ? null : new CallVm { Id = call.Id, UserFullname = call.User?.Username };
    }
}
```

Pass mapper to repository and ensure that your objects are not connected with DB anymore

```
public class CallRepository : ICallRepository
{
    private readonly ICallMapper _callMapper;

    public CallRepository(ICallMapper callMapper)
    {
        _callMapper = callMapper;
    }

    public IList<CallVm> GetList()
    {
        // Call DB and get entities
        var calls = GetCalls();

        // Map DB entities to plain model
        return calls.Select(_callMapper.Map).ToList();
    }
}
```

This lets you to get rid of your error. And makes your program more structable and testable.