# using a lazily loaded ICollection in another model property - object disposed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lazy-loading

I'm trying to use a lazily loaded ICollection in another model property like so... (note: I've only included the class properties related to this question as the class has over 50 properties and trimmed the `TotalCost` property down to include only the error causing line.)

```
    public class PartModel {
        public double TotalCost
        {
            get
            {
                var costs = 0D;
                costs += AddedCosts != null && AddedCosts.Any() ? AddedCosts.Sum(x => x.AddedCost) : 0;
                return double.IsInfinity(costs) ? 0 : costs;
            }
        }
        public virtual ICollection<AddedCostModel> AddedCosts { get; set; }
    }
```

When I call `AddedCosts` in a view, it lazily loads up fine as one would expect, but when `TotalCost` is called, immediately after `AddedCosts`, an exception is thrown `Error: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.`

What do i need to change here to allow this to work? should I be eagerly loading this rather than lazily?

Comment: My advice would be not to use lazy loading ever, but *especially* in a web app. It's simply not worth it.

Comment: Okay, I'm willing to listen, what's your reasoning?

Comment: There's plenty of resources out there, here's one I found with a simple Google https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54386019/should-entity-framework-lazy-loading-be-disabled-in-web-apps

Comment: @DavidG Thanks for the info. The arguments are solid and I've reconsidered my design, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy Loading in web apps is inefficient and is a poor design.
Don't use it.